# AWS Cloudwatch shows CPU Utilization very low each time ECS scaling

Tags: cpu-usage, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-fargate

For each time ECS Fargate service scales in or out, Cloudwatch show the CPU  utilization with very low percent (about `2 -> 3%`) (same with Memory) on graph and then it will be increased gradually although before that time, it's quite high  (polices: `80% for scaling out, 40% for scaling in`).

I just worry if there is any unavailable period (or break-time) when it's scaling?

Answer (score 2):

> I just worry if there is any unavailable period (or break-time) when it's scaling?

Technically, at the Fargate level, the answer is no as long as you have your service set with a minimum task count >= 1.

The wiggle room in saying "no" though, is if your app spikes from 70% CPUUtilization to 100%, the application itself may become unresponsive before Cloudwatch is able to trigger an alarm which in turn triggers the service to scale out.

---

> although before that time, it's quite high

Keep in mind, scaling actions aren't instantaneous. If you're using a Cloudwatch metric for CPUUtilization with a period of 60 seconds, and a threshold of 2, that means your task would have to be > 80% utilization for over 2 minutes before autoscaling was triggered.

In addition to this, Fargate startup time is slower than ECS launch type startup time, because AWS has to do some magic behind the scenes - specifically download the image and also attach an ENI - to make it "serverless".

So, if your application goes over 80% utilization, you wouldn't see it autoscale immediately. This might explain what you're seeing in Cloudwatch with the utilization being high enough to trigger scaling, dropping off to 2% but after the scaling has already been triggered.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I still don't understand why it was dropping off too much after scaling. If the current rate is 80%, then after scaling, it should be something like 40% (if the number of containers is increased to be doubled), but 2% is weird. How do you think?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about what's running in the containers, the full ECS service setup for autoscaling, cpu/memory limits at the task level, hosts specs. You're looking at CPUUtilization, which can vary based on workload as well. Lots of moving parts.